# name 'tel' is not defined

Tags: python

```py
import json
from random import choice
def gen_person():
    tel = ''

nums = ['1' ,'2','3', '4' , '5']

while len(tel) != 7:
    tel +=  choice(nums)
    print(tel)

def main():
    gen_person()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Что Вы пытаетесь сделать этим кодом? Непосредственно ошибка связана с тем, что переменная `tel` объявлена в локальной области видимости функции `gen_person` и недоступна из глобально области видимости.

Answer (score 4):

Соблюдайте отступы:

```
import json
from random import choice
def gen_person():
    tel = ''

    nums = ['1' ,'2','3', '4' , '5']

    while len(tel) != 7:
       tel +=  choice(nums)

    print(tel)

def main():
   gen_person()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```